# Laravel can't understand why Trying to get property of non-object is occurring?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `MembersController` the contains the following.

```
public function indexPaid()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    if(!Auth::user()->picked_tools)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->subscribedToPlan('one-tool',   'member')) return redirect('/pick-tools')->with('status', 'You have subscribed to use one of my products! Please select which product below you would like to use.');
        if(Auth::user()->subscribedToPlan('all-tools',  'member')) return redirect('/pick-tools')->with('status', 'You have subscribed to use all of my products! Please select which products below you would like to use.');
    }
    else
    {
        return view('membersHome')->with('productsWeCanUse', \App\ToolSelection::GetUsersProducts());
    }
}
```

All works fine locally and also in production when tested. However in my production laravel logs I'm seeing this error.

```
Trying to get property of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at MembersController.php:93)
```

Line 93 is

```
if(!Auth::user()->picked_tools)
```

As I'm applying the auth middleware I can't understand how `picked_tools` can sometimes not be in the Auth object or the Auth object not be present at that point?

`picked_tools` is a column on my users table. Its always there, there no other interaction with it in the script.

What could be going wrong here? Again, tested locally and in production I can't replicate this error, but I see it frequently in the production logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't define middleware in action. Use constructor for that.

> However, it is more convenient to specify middleware within your
>   controller's constructor.

[(docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers)

You must do it as follows

```
public function __construct()
{
    // this will only apply middleware to one action
    $this->middleware('auth')->only('indexPaid');
}
```

UPD. You got error since you define middleware apply not in a right place. It must be **already defined** when you access the action. So use routes file or the controller constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It means the current user is not authentication. You should do the check:

```
if (auth()->check() && !auth()->user()->picked_tools) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: does the $this->middleware('auth') not redirect them and stop execution past that point?

Comment: @jamie yes, but you should move it to the constructor. Or better to routes.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan if you're asking about `$this->middleware('auth')`, it should be moved to the constructor or routes.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to explain. Your answer is simply wrong. The reason is not that user is not authenticated but that he placed middleware in the wrong place. Middleware must be applied _before_ request is routed to a specific action. You can't apply it inside an action.

Comment: _It's best to envision middleware as a series of "layers" HTTP requests must pass through *before* they hit your application._ (c) docs
You wrote correct thing, but you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan that does not make my answer wrong. It's just another solution to the same problem. That's not a reason for downvoting. I also told OP about middleware the same time you've posted your answer.